# Using Scalar Function in Crystal Report and VB6

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports, vb6, user-defined-functions

I want to print crystal report using vb6, but the case is :
I have the query

```
"SELECT Total, dbo.ToWord(Total) as WordTotal FROM TblBankTransfer"
```

The `dbo.ToWord` is a scalar user defined function in my SQL Server which receive numeric paramter and converts it to words.

This query is assigned to `CrBBK.SQLQuery` to call crystal report.
But I can't print this `WordTotal` in my Crystal Report and always get error, because the column is not in `TblBankTransfer`.

Any Idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to create a stored procedure which calls the function and does the processing and use this procedure in CR.

Comment: This is not a problem of the scalar function... but problem with database, because error says there is no column of that type in table.. check database table structure

Comment: @Siva It isn't a problem with the scalar function, but it isn't a problem with the database table structure either.  The problem is that the `WordTotal` field that the OP wants to print is a calculated field.  Therefore it is only in the result set, not in the table.  Bhatt's solution is the correct one; using the result set from calling a stored procedure as the source data in Crystal Reports, instead of using a table reference.